# Magento2.2.4 : Uninstall a theme throw exceptions?

Tags: magento2, theme, exception, magento2.2.4, uninstall

I have created a theme and then uninstalled it. The storefront or admin view is not using that theme further. But when I restart the server it gives exceptions as follows.

How can be fixed this?

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception 0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException): Bucket does not exist
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException): Bucket does
>   not exist
>   0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection/Interceptor.php(115):
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection->getFacetedData('category')
>   1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php(111):
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor->getFacetedData('category')
>
> 2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/AbstractFilter.php(202):
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category->_getItemsData()
>
> 3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/AbstractFilter.php(159):
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->_initItems()
>
> 4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/AbstractFilter.php(148):
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->getItems()
>
> 5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Category/AvailabilityFlag.php(33):
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->getItemsCount()
>
> 6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Category/AvailabilityFlag.php(23):
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag->canShowOptions(Array)
>   7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/Block/Navigation.php(111):
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag->isEnabled(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\Interceptor),
>   Array)
>   8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml(17):
>   Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation->canShowBlock()
>   9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59):
>   include('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
>   10 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270):
>   Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation),
>   '/opt/lampp/htdo...', Array)
>   11 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
>   12 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
>   13 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
>   14 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('catalog.leftnav')
>   15 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('catalog.leftnav')
>   16 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('catalog.leftnav')
>   17 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('catalog.leftnav', true)
>   18 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('catalog.leftnav')
>   19 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content.top')
>   20 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content.top')
>   21 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content.top')
>   22 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content.top', true)
>   23 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content.top')
>   24 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main')
>   25 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
>   26 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main')
>   27 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', true)
>   28 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main')
>   29 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns')
>   30 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
>   31 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
>   32 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', true)
>   33 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns')
>   34 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content')
>   35 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
>   36 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
>   37 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', true)
>   38 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content')
>   39 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
>   40 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
>   41 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
>   42 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
>   43 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
>   44 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
>   45 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
>   46 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
>   47 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
>   48 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
>   49 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
>   50 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput',
>   Array)
>   51 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
>   52 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput',
>   Array, Array)
>   53 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
>   54 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>   55 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>   56 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult',
>   Array)
>   57 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>   58 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult',
>   Array, Array)
>   59 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>   60 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
>   61 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
>   62 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
>   63 {main}

Comment: Are you able to access admin ?

Comment: @NikunjVadariya Yes, it is possible. It cannot be loaded the website's home page or any page.

Comment: Try my answer it will help you.

Comment: Magento team fixed this issue In magento 2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should know that this is a common issue with Magento 2.2.

After the update, the Root category is not anchored, even if set to "`Yes`".

So you can go ahead and switch it off and then on again (`Save`) and it should resolve the issue.

## **Or**

You can be fixed this issue by updating Magento version. In magento 2.3 issue is resolved.